# Unexpected defer behaviours

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a function that does processing asynchronously:

```
func something(completion: [Something] -> Void) {
  dispatch_async(queue) {
    ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      completion(something)
    }
  }
}
```

I thought it would be wise to use `defer` to guarantee that `completion` gets called every time, so I tried this:

```
func something(completion: [Something] -> Void) {
  dispatch_async(queue) {
    ...
    defer {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        completion(something)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Working well. Then I tried to use a `guard` statement within the asynchronous dispatch that always failed, to see if `defer` will activate. It didn't:

```
func something(completion: [Something] -> Void) {
  dispatch_async(queue) {
    ...
    guard let shouldFail = ... else { return }
    defer {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        completion(something)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`defer` would not be called. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `defer` after returning. The compiler doesn't know that you specified `defer` instructions (because it returned already and didn't see any defer instructions in that point, so the next lines are not fired up). If you'd move `defer {}` before the guard, then it will be called.

Answer (score 1):

`guard` will return before even getting to the `defer`. Try doing it the other way around:

```
func something(completion: [Something] -> Void) {
  dispatch_async(queue) {
    ...
    defer {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        completion(something)
      }
    }
    guard let shouldFail = ... else { return }
  }
}
```